# What does the sentence "What do you understand about your business that other companies in it just don't get" mean?

Tags: meaning

A startup investor says the following:

> *What do you understand about your business that other companies in it just don't get?*

I don't understand.  What do they mean? What does *it* mean? What is *don't get* in the sentence?

Comment: what's the source? What's the context? Where was it spoken?

Comment: ycombinator.com

Comment: Be specific. Don't give Homepage URL. I cannot find the phrase anywhere on the page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. "It" refers to "your business."

   We can rephrase the sentence to:

   > What do you understand about your business that other companies in [your business] just don't get?
2. The word "get" in "just don't get" means:

   > <sub>[Meaning of "get" from Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/get)</sub>
   >
   > 15. To understand (often used as get it).

   We can rephrase the sentence to:

   > What do you understand about your business that other companies in [your business] just don't [understand]?

   For example, for a company that makes hats:

   > What do you understand about [making hats] that other companies in [hat making] just don't understand?

<sub>Still don't *get* it? Try reading [some sample answers to this question.](https://www.google.com.ph/search?q=%22What%20do%20you%20understand%20about%20your%20business%20that%20other%20companies%20in%20it%20just%20don%27t%20get?%22&oq=%22What%20do%20you%20understand%20about%20your%20business%20that%20other%20companies%20in%20it%20just%20don%27t%20get?%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.1934j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)</sub>

Comment: *it* refers to **the similar business** and not *your business*. *What do you understand about your business that other companies in [the same business] just don't get?*

Comment: @MaulikV It's arguable since "business" can (roughly) be A) *A specific establishment* or B) *A field or trade*. In this context, I think it's B.

Comment: ok, thank you, cos I thought "your business" means "your company", so that is wrong right. does "your business" mean "your business industry" or "your business area"?

Comment: @Tim Added an example.

Comment: +1.  Everything in this answer seems correct, so I don't know why it was downvoted.

Comment: I agree. Using "in your industry" probably would have saved some confusion, but hey, as they say, hindsight's twenty-twenty. Meanwhile, I had upvoted this anyway :).

Answer (score 4):

Helix's answer is totally fine, but I'm going to use some examples to make it clearer.

Let's say you're going to start a car manufacturing business and you need an investor. Now, an investor would want to be sure that he'd get good returns on his investment. So he asks you this question:

> There are other companies in this business. **Why should I invest in your company? What do you understand about your business [car manufacturing] that other companies in it [car manufacturing] just don't get [don't understand]?**

Because if you know more about this business than other companies, then obviously you are going to make profit and I would get good returns on my investment.